# Memory-to-memory copy

Tags: memory, x86, copy

Is there a mechanism of efficiently simulating a memory-to-memory copy using x86 instructions?

I need to guarantee an instant in time when both the source address and the destination address point to equal values. I am currently using a loop (i.e. do { reg = *A; *B = reg; } while (reg != *A) ), but I'd like to optimize on that.

EDIT: Missed some important information: I'm copying pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REP MOVSB (google it), there's also WORD and DWORD versions, probably QWORDs by now too

Comment: At this moment I realized I should have been more specific on the nature of the data I'm trying to copy: I'm copying pointers, so movs* falls short on 64bit architectures (since the largest amount that can be atomically copied is a dword). However, thank you for your informative post.

Comment: Actually there is the QWORD version as well, just not documented in most places. Thank you!